# How to attach to an existing Java EE session

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, session-variables

I have an external SOAP web service that attaches to our services layer inside the application. For the Web 2.0 application, the services layer uses the session to store the user's "key chain" or the things a user can do in the system.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing with my web service client to our services layer. The problem is that the web service URL can't contain a cookie that holds the session ID. (If I'm wrong, please say how and I'll do it that way.)

When the web service client connects the first time, I require a login and generate a security key that uniquely identifies that user and will expire within a certain period requiring them to login again.

I'd like to find a way in my endpoints to re-attach to the proper session for that security key and then the security will work automatically.

My endpoints are currently being served from tomcat.

How can I get there from here?

All input appreciated.

Comment: How does a SOAP service 'attach' to another service? A service normally is called by a client. Where is the client?

Comment: @Tichodroma The services I'm referring to are our business services that are defined in java jar files. I want to simply link to these and run them directly. There will be several clients of the web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using REST to come back into our webapp through the URL so that I have a session. I connected to it that way.